# customized "scale_color_gradient2" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use my own specific color in my image plot. I am very new in ggplot2 so had a look at its manual from [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_gradient2.html) - the old link does not exist and now is [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html) - and tried to repeat some of the stuff; but I couldn't figure out how to supply my colorbar as I did for the graphics plot.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

#my specific color list
mycol <- vector(length=512, mode = "numeric")
for (k in 1:256) mycol[k] <- rgb(255, k - 1, k - 1, maxColorValue=255)
for (k in 257:512) mycol[k] <- rgb(511 - (k - 1), 511 - (k - 1), 255, maxColorValue=255)
mycol <- rev(mycol)
ncolors <- length(mycol)

# graphics plot
par(mar = c(5, 13, 1, 6))
image(1:ncol(volcano), 1:nrow(volcano), t(volcano), zlim = c(0, ncolors), col=mycol, axes=FALSE, main="W Matrix", sub = "", xlab= "Components", ylab="Genes")
axis(2, at=1:nrow(volcano), labels=row.names(volcano), adj= 0.5, tick=FALSE, las = 1, cex.axis=0.25, font.axis=1, line=-1)
axis(1, at=1:ncol(volcano), labels=colnames(volcano), adj= 0.5, tick=FALSE,las = 3, cex=1, cex.axis=0.5, font.axis=1, line=-1)


# ggplot2
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(ez)
ggplot(melt(volcano), aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + scale_color_gradient2(low = muted("red"), mid = "white", high = muted("blue"), midpoint = 0, space = "rgb", guide = "colourbar") # the code does not really use my color bar
```

> Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0

Comment: Just replace scale_color_gradient2() with scale_fill_gradient2() as you are using fill= inside aes()

Comment: thanks, how can I use my own colorbar as I did in the lattice plot.

Comment: I can't reproduce your lattice colorbar because you didn't provide variable myorig

Comment: ...and that isn't a lattice plot, anyhow, its base graphics. Nor do I see how that code could produce a colorbar at all.

Comment: @DidzisElferts I have updated the code. feel free to change rownames/colnames to anything else !

Comment: @joran sorry if I called it wrong. I will update the post. from line 5 I am making my colorbar and it is called "mycol". I am using this variable as a parameter in line 12, "col=mycol".

Comment: I am sorry, might be I should have call it color bar ! should I call it my color list ?! or ?

Comment: Ok, so you want to know how to use those _specific_ colors in your fill scale in ggplot.

Comment: @joran yes. similar to my graphics plot

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify @Didzis' answer, which works but may not produce the gradient you're looking for...

'midpoint' refers to the numerical value at which you want the color specified by 'mid' to appear. So, instead of setting the 'midpoint' argument to 256 (which falls outside the range of `value`, which is the vector you're coloring by), it's wise to set it to a value somewhere in the middle of the range of values you are coloring by, otherwise you aren't using the entire gradient you specified with 'low' and 'high', which defeats the purpose of `scale_color_gradient2`. The exact value depends on what you are trying to communicate visually, but usually the mean or median is used. Here, I edited @Didzis' code with 'midpoint' set to the median of `value`

```
v <- melt(volcano)
ggplot(v, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#0000FF", mid = "#FFFFFF", high ="#FF0000", 
                       midpoint = median(v$value), space = "rgb", guide = "colourbar")
```

This gives a plot with a much wider gradient:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change values for `low=`, `mid=` and `high=` values in `scale_fill_gradient2()`. For `low=` I used first value of `mycol`, for `high=` last value of `mycol` and for `mid=` used 256. value (middle). Also changed `midpoint=` to 256 as this is midpoint of your number of colors.

```
ggplot(melt(volcano), aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#0000FF", mid = "#FFFFFF", high ="#FF0000", 
                       midpoint = 256.5, space = "rgb", guide = "colourbar")
```

[image]